# Envers, PostgreSQL and TINYINT

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate-envers

We are using Envers with both Oracle and MySQL without any problem. We are now trying PostgreSQL but we have the problem that the audit tables are created with a column `REVTYPE` of type `TINYINT`.

`TINYINT` is not supported by PostgreSQL.

Is there a way to change the type of `REVTYPE`?

Example:

```
create table AUD_SomeTable (
  dbId bigint not null,
  ...
  REV integer not null,
  REVTYPE tinyint,
  primary key (dbId, REV)
);
```

**EDIT**:

Problem solved: I forgot the change the Hibernate dialect.

Comment: how do changed it @Matteo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about about Envers, but you could create a new [domain type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createdomain.html).

```
CREATE DOMAIN "tinyint"
  AS smallint;
```

You can add CONSTRAINS to check for e.g. a postive value.

Comment: Thanks for the answer: this works but I noticed that I just forgot to change the Hibernate dialect setting ...

Answer (score 3):

You should test  whether this is really an Envers issue or an Hibernate issue. Try mapping an entity with a property `byte type` using hibernate only. If it tries to generate a `tinyint` column it would be a Hibernate issue.

Comment: It was a configuration issue. Specifying the correct Hibernate dialect solved the problem.

Comment: @Matteo Which dialect did you use?

Comment: @Matteo thanks for the quick answer :) Do you have any idea how to fix the issue nowadays? I just ran into the same issue with hibernate envers, flyway and postgres

Comment: Hi I just want to quickly link another post regarding this issue: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35925228/hibernate-entity-auditing-and-hbm2ddl-auto-validate-in-h2-and-oracle) ... Now my validation works and I can still use a h2 database.