# Hibernate Entity Auditing and hbm2ddl.auto=validate in h2 and oracle

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, h2, hibernate-envers

I have a problem with schema validation of revtype column of  audit tables  
I  have declared revtype column as number(3) everything is working fine when i'm using oracle database but when i'm switch to h2 i have exception revtype 
 
 
**revtype column found decimal expected tinyint**

Any ideas how can it works on h2 and oracle ?

Comment: What is java data type for revtype?

Comment: I don't know it is in envers internals

Answer (score 1):

Extending h2 dialect and changing column definition for integer worked

Comment: hi @Bartun did you do something like this to fix the h2 dialect: `registerColumnType(Types.TINYINT, "smallint");` ?

Comment: Yes,  but so far I remember it put decimal so it will be compatible with oracle